# In IE the Post Back is only working after the console is open

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, sharepoint-2013, internet-explorer-11

The Postback redirection in SharePoint is working fine in Chrome and firefox. but IE 11 the redirection is nor working properly.

I have used the below javascript code

```
 var publishButton = $("input[id$=SaveItem]");
            // change redirection behavior
            publishButton.removeAttr("onclick");

            publishButton.on('click',function() {

                var elementName = $(this).attr("name");
                var aspForm = document.forms['aspnetForm'];
                var oldPostbackUrl = aspForm.action;
                if (SPClientForms.ClientFormManager.SubmitClientForm('WPQ2')) return false;
                var currentSourceValue = GetUrlKeyValue("Source", true, oldPostbackUrl);
                var newPostbackUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+"/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx";
                var newPostbackUrl = oldPostbackUrl.replace(currentSourceValue,newPostbackUrl );
                if (!PreSaveItem()) return false;
                setTimeout(function(){
                    WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(elementName, "", true, "", newPostbackUrl, false, true));
                },1);       
            });
```

Suggest idea to do in IE 11 redirection.

Comment: Why the setTimeout?

Comment: For firefox needs the setTimeout.without the setTimeout the click button is not working properly in firefox .

Answer (score -1):

Before you do anything else, try this first:

```
        document.getElementById("yourElementName").addEventListener("click", function(event){
                  event.preventDefault()
       });
```

Comment: I don't understand .please say briefly.

Comment: You are removing the click from an element and it's fine. But you also must prevent that element's default behavior for clicks. So, by applying my answer first, you disable that default behavior. After that implement what you want.